# Requesting any row that matches optional criteria in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express, elasticsearch

basically what I want to do is the following. Using React and Express I created a web page, in which specifically, one part is in charge of searching users. **The problem is that not all the inputs always exist in the request, and I would like to bring from the database all those rows that match at least 1 of the fields**.

For example, suppose I have the User table with the following fields: name, email and address. Now, from the frontend the user only puts the name of the person (therefore the other two fields would be incomplete). My intention is that **all the existing matches are brought from the database (Even if the name input is incomplete)**.

Another example:
[image: Another example]

The first thing I did was look for **search engines** that I could use so that I didn't have to think and develop the query logic myself. This is how I found **ElasticSearch**, which I was looking for a lot and I understand that it can be done but it does not seem to be something "correct", since ElasticSearch works with Documents (more oriented to NoSQL DB). Next, I found something called **"Full Text Search"**, which seems to be a kind of technique to develop an efficient algorithm.

What solution can I implement? The truth is, I looked everywhere and I am lost because it gives me the impression that what I want to do is not possible, or perhaps very far-fetched.

Comment: *I would like to bring from the database all those rows that match at least 1 of the fields.* If so then separate conditions must be combined using OR operator. *the user only puts the name of the person (therefore the other two fields would be incomplete)* Exclude conditions by non-specified criteria from the query, or add the checking that the parameter is set.

Answer (score 0):

"Full Text Search" is a MySQL feature that use a fulltext index on field that provide a good way to search text on a text field with many characters or words.

In your case, I see two solutions :

- simply use a LIKE statement (email LIKE '%email%'),
- use a powerful search engine like Apache SOLR, indexing fields like you want, with great search criteria, but this solution is useful if complex search needed.

So the first solution I think suits your case, the second is like using a bazooka on a fly ;-)